# Determine element number in a set : handling null and zero element

Tags: java, set

I have a simple set class. In the class, I have some methods such as: add element, count set size, etc. The code looks like:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;   
public class MySet {    
    public int numOfElem;
    public int totalNum;
    public int[] arraySet=new int[100];;
    Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();

    public MySet()
    {
        numOfElem=0;
        totalNum=0;
        //int[] arraySet=new int[100];          
    }

    public void makeSet()
    {
      for(int i:arraySet)
          set.add(i);
    }

    public int size()
    {
        makeSet();
        numOfElem=set.size();
        return numOfElem-1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if(numOfElem==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        int[] arraySet=new int[100];
        numOfElem=0;
        totalNum=0;
    }

    public boolean contains(int n)
    {
        boolean isContains=false;
        for(int i=0;i<totalNum;i++)
            {
              if(arraySet[i]==n)
                isContains=true;
            }
        return isContains;
    }

    public void add(int n)
    {   
        arraySet[totalNum]=n;
        makeSet();
        totalNum++;
    }
public String toString()
    {
        String str="";
        for(int i=0;i<totalNum;i++)
        str= str+arraySet[i]+" ";       
        return str;
    }  



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySet simpleSet =new MySet();
        simpleSet.add(1);
        System.out.println(simpleSet.set);
        System.out.println(simpleSet.size());
        System.out.println("Hello there!");
    }   
}
```

My question are

(1) When I add "1" into the set, the set would say I have [0,1] in the set, which is easy to understand, because when I initialize the array, array[0-99] are 0. But How can I avoid output 0 here please?

(2)If I use if statement to avoid output 0, it is not wise. Because what if I have to input '0' to the set, how to analyze this question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `makeSet()` method should only add items up to `totalNum` instead of the entire `arraySet` array. I'd also change the order of execution in `add()` to avoid potential unwanted behaviour:

```
public void add(int n)
{   
    arraySet[totalNum]=n;
    totalNum++;
    makeSet();
}

public void makeSet()
{
  for(int i=0;i<totalNum;i++)
      set.add(arraySet[i]);
}
```

Note that this only solves the problem you asked about, there are numerous other problems in the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask for your other suggestions please?

Comment: @guangde `makeSet()` should not iterate over all items *and* be called in every `add()` & `size()`. `contains()` should break once a match is found. `empty()` declares an unused local `arraySet` variable. And the whole approach of keeping an actual `HashSet` to avoid duplicates kind of defeats the purpose of implementing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use an array of Integer objects instead of int because this way the default value of every element in the set is null, so you can just check for null, like this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MySet {
    public int numOfElem;
    public int totalNum;
    public Integer[] arraySet = new Integer[100];
    ;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    public MySet() {
        numOfElem = 0;
        totalNum = 0;
        //int[] arraySet=new int[100];          
    }

    public void makeSet() {
        for(Integer i : arraySet) {
            if(i != null) {
                set.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        makeSet();
        numOfElem = set.size();
        return numOfElem - 1;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(numOfElem == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void clear() {
        arraySet = new Integer[100];
        numOfElem = 0;
        totalNum = 0;
    }

    public boolean contains(int n) {
        boolean isContains = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
            if(arraySet[i] == n)
                isContains = true;
        }
        return isContains;
    }

    public void add(int n) {
        arraySet[totalNum] = n;
        makeSet();
        totalNum++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySet simpleSet = new MySet();
        simpleSet.add(1);
        simpleSet.add(0);
        System.out.println(simpleSet.set);
        System.out.println(simpleSet.size());
        System.out.println("Hello there!");
    }
}
```

But something that you may not be aware of ist that a Set cannot store two elements that are the same, so if you were to add the number one twice, you would only get it once in the output